# Safari & Chrome freezing when focusing a Select in iOS

Tags: ios, html, google-chrome, select, safari

I have a reoccurring problem with Safari and Chrome on iOS freezing when a Select is focused. I've seen some older posts about this but with no resolutions.

I have a page with a fairly high number of HTML inputs and selects. I tried to design the page in a way to use DIVs that look like inputs to lower the overall count, but some of them are still needed.

Here is the page in question:
http://www.pokedit.com/pokemon-maker/index.php

The page doesn't always freeze when focusing, but when it does, it's for a long time and the browser usually crashes.

Info:

- There are some selects on the page that are display:none or inside hidden DIVS. Some of those can be revealed by changing different toggles.
- There are no input type="hidden" inputs on the page.
- The freezing problem does not happen in Android, Windows, Mac, or Ubuntu in any browsers that I've tested.

Comment: Will there ever be a solution for this? *faint sound of the wind blows thru the spring foliage*

Doesn't seem likely...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Apple is an amazing company and designs their software well, you're going to have to compensate by heavily altering your design even though it works fine in every other modern browser. Think of iOS as the EI 6 of our time. It's sure to leave a legacy.

Now it's back to the drawing board for you and anyone else with this delightful technicality. You're going to enjoy wasting lots of time writing code to do things with basic functionality that selects and inputs are already supposed to do. That will ensure your pages can load just a smidgen slower whilst wasting a bunch of time and effort writing extra code for no reason at all.

Special thanks to Steve Jorbs.